# Define category ID using get_post_meta

Tags: php, categories, custom-field, post-meta

I need to define the Category ID in my singles page through custom fields so that i can load a different category depending on the page. This is what i have so far and its not working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks.

```
 <?php query_posts( 'cat=<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'BarID', true); ?>id&showposts=1000' ); ?>

<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
      <!-- BEER ITEM -->
            <div class="menu-title">
            <span><?php the_title(); ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="menu-desc-wrap">
            <div class="beer-discripton">
            <span></span>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="percent"><span> <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Percent', true); ?></span></div>
            </div>
            <!-- BEER ITEM END -->
<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php else : ?>

<p>Not Found</p>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Ive also tried this:

```
<?php $cataID = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'cata', false); ?>

        <div class="one-half column">
        <h3 class="title-color"><img class="img-valign-draft" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/draft-bottle/draft.svg" alt="">Draft</h3>

           <?php query_posts( 'cat='$cata'&showposts=1000' ); ?>

<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
      <!-- BEER ITEM -->
            <div class="menu-title">
            <span><?php the_title(); ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="menu-desc-wrap">
            <div class="beer-discripton">
            <span></span>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="percent"><span> <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Percent', true); ?></span></div>
            </div>
            <!-- BEER ITEM END -->
<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php else : ?>

<p>Not Found</p>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Are you storing cateroy in a meta field? Why if the category is already assigned and can be get using, for example, [`get_the_category()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category)?

Comment: I need to be able to set the category from a wordpress post, as i am only using the one single.php

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand you. You can set the category when you edit/create a post. Then you can get the category that the post belongs to through several mehtods, like `get_the_category()` function, meta fields are not involved. I don't understnd what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
global $wp_query;
 $cata = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'cata', false);  
query_posts (
array(
    'cat'=> $cata,
    'showposts' =>'1000'
    )
);
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
  <!-- BEER ITEM -->
        <div class="menu-title">
        <span><?php the_title(); ?></span>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-desc-wrap">
        <div class="beer-discripton">
        <span></span>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="percent"><span> <?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'Percent', true ); ?></span></div>
        </div>
        <!-- BEER ITEM END -->
<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```